# Implementation of Koebe–Andreev–Thurston circle packing?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, knot-theory, computational-geometry, planar-graphs

The circle packing theorem (Koebe–Andreev–Thurston theorem) claims for a planar graph, we can pack disjoint circles, such that: the circles correspond to vertices and the disks are tangent if the vertices are adjacent.

I would like to implement this algorithm in computer code (input: graph, output: circle packing). Where can I find a readable (not too complex) version of the procedure? I do not need the theory behind it. I know it has been implemented (e.g. in KnotTheory package in Mathematica), but I'm interested in the algorithm itself, not a software that does it.

Comment: It might help to examine existing code, e.g., [Robert Syzymanski's C++ code](https://github.com/robertszymanski/bubblechallenge), or [Ken Stephenson's MatLab GOPack code](https://github.com/kensmath/GOPack).

Comment: Actually, I found an excellent Python implementation by David Eppstein in his [PADS library](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/). Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Here is Ken Stephenson's book on the subject: "Introduction to Circle Packing: The Theory of Discrete Analytic Functions".  The wikipedia page has many more references - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem

Ah, and see the references given at this very closely related post - [Koebe–Andreev–Thurston theorem - where can I find a proof?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187845/koebe-andreev-thurston-theorem-where-can-i-find-a-proof)