# Proofs of circle packing theorem

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, circle-packing

Circle packing theorem is a famous result stating that for every connected simple planar graph $G$ there is a circle packing in the plane whose intersection graph is $G$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem.

I know that this result has many proofs and I want to read one of them, but don't understand how to start (for quite a while). The article in wiki gives a reference to Thurston notes, but the proof comes only in the last section and I am not sure if this is the simplest approach. I like these notes very much, but was never able to read them till the end. So I wonder if there are some simple proofs of this result nowadays. Can you advise something?

Comment: may be the fact that there exists a triangulation of every maximal planar graph may come handy in the proof

Comment: Does this answer to your question?https://mathoverflow.net/q/187845/90655

Comment: Thanks a lot C.F.G! I have not spotted this question. It looks like mine is a duplicate. I'll study the answers

Comment: Although your question is close to a duplicate to "[Koebe–Andreev–Thurston theorem - where can I find a proof?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/187845/6094)," additional expositions have appeared in the ~6 yrs since that post.

Answer (score 8):

I can recommend Sariel Har-Peled's exposition in supplemental
Chapter 15 of his book
*Geometric Approximation Algorithms*.
[Ch15 PDF download](https://sarielhp.org/book/chapters/planar_circle_packing.pdf).
He emphasizes angles via a "whac-an-angle" game.
He acknowledges that

> Our presentation follows Pach and Agarwal [[pa-cg-95](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118033203)].

---

[image]

[image]

---

Answer (score 3):

[Books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Circle_Packing) are [written](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11224) on the subject, so, finding a proof (which are many by now) shouldn't be a problem. I also enjoyed greatly [Rohde's tribute to Schramm](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aop/1318940778) that explains in very nice way some ideas that Schramm introduced into the area; following references from there one should be able to find more detailed accounts.